# Npm building fails because of optional chaining

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, optional-chaining

I am developing a project using laravel, so that means I'm using mix to compile javascript. I have syntax like

```
 return this.page?.sidebar_text_color
```

When I run npm run dev or npm run watch, I get compilation error

```
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining (https://git.io/vb4Sk) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation
```

[image]

The thing is, I have already set this up earlier and everything was working fine it just stopped working all of a sudden today.
Here's my package.json fragment regarding babel

```
"babel": {
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I have everything set up and yet still, npm is telling me to install that plugin for babel. What could be wrong?

Comment: have you any found solution ?

Comment: @سعيد I can't remember now but I think I had to downgrade my npm to earlier version, which solved this issue

Comment: how did you do that , did you install older version of NodeJS ?

Comment: wan I use nvm to achieve that ?